# changing content of text view on button click inside listview

Tags: android, listview

[this is the image of layout tile.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxbm3.png)
i have created a list using custom adapter it has 2 textviews and 2 buttons inside it now what i want is to change the visiblity of one of textview on button click.

I am handling the button clicks outside the custom adapter.I want to toggle visiblity toggle for second textview with id tvstatus using on and off buttons.

this is code for customadapter

```
package slide.apptech.com.rpiconnect;

/**
 * Created by MOHIT on 09-06-2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//custom adapter class extends a arrayadapter
public class customadapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList values;
    private String stv = "Ststus";

    public customadapter2(Context context, ArrayList values) {

        //for super constructor pass
        // context files
        //layout file required for list
        //arraylist that has strings to be displayed
        super(context, R.layout.tile, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;
        final ViewGroup par = parent;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, parent, false);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvappname);
        Button on = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bon);
        Button off = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.boff);
        final TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus);

        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                ((ListView) par).performItemClick(v, pos, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()

            }
        });

        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) ;
                ((ListView) par).performItemClick(v, pos, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
            }
        });

        //get(position method is used to access the elements of arraylist)
        String val = (String) values.get(position);
        textView.setText(val);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = (String) values.get(position);

        return rowView;
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View v)
    {

    }
}
```

this is code for my xml file that i am using as listelement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#611818"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OFF"
            android:id="@+id/boff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bon"
            android:text="ON"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ttile"
            android:id="@+id/tvappname"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/boff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ON"
                android:id="@+id/tvstatus"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvappname"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="#060505"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

please comment if you want any other file

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do that. Changing the value directly of any view inside listview is a bad idea. Just make changes in your arraylist and then call notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect changes.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)    {
    final int pos = position;
    final ViewGroup par = parent;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, parent, false);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvappname);
    Button on = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bon);
    Button off = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.boff);
    final TextView status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus);
    //get(position method is used to access the elements of arraylist)
    String val = (String) values.get(position);
    textView.setText(val);
    if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("off")){
        status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            values.set(position, "On");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((ListView) par).performItemClick(v, pos, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
        }
    });

    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            values.set(position, "Off");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((ListView) par).performItemClick(v, pos, 0); // Let the event be handled in onItemClick()
        }
    });

    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = (String) values.get(position);

    return rowView;
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I am sure you are using arraylist for keeping status, and if status is off then you have to hide your editText?

Comment: no i am not using arraylist to store status it has default value 'on' see xml file

Comment: Right, then change visibility, by checking your status. if it is off then make it invisible, otherwise make it visible. For that on click of off button change the value of your arraylist and notifyDatasetchange(), wait I am making correction in your code :)

Comment: Updated my post, let me know in case of any confusion :)

Comment: i tried out your solution it works but the problem is that the arraylist values is not being used for status is being used for title of the tile so insted of changing the status the title of tile gets changed isn't there a way to do it without using arraylist?? i have added the image for xml file

Comment: Please explain little bit more, what exactly you want. Do you want to set title from your arrayLIst and change the value on/off using your buttons.

Comment: Use ViewHolder Pattern instead of just inflating to layout on each item